# Find the minimum possible value $M$

Tags: combinatorics

> $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are non-negative real numbers adding up to $1$. If $$M=\max \{a+b+c, b+c+d, c+d+e, d+e+f,e+f+g\},$$
>
> find the minimum possible value that $M$ can take as $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ vary.

Please give me some idea to solve this.

Comment: What's the lowest value that _you_ can make $M$ be, just by trying a few different things?

Comment: Please clarify a bit more, @Arthur

Comment: Well, have you tried different things? Like having $a = 1$ and the rest equal to $0$? Having them all equal? Having them all nearly equal, but one _slightly_ larger and one _slightly_ smaller? Having every other being $0$ and the rest as large as possible? What does $M$ become in those cases?

Comment: what's happened to f+g+a and g+a+b?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry They're probably omitted to make this slightly trickier.

Comment: @Arthur; how does that make it trickier?

Comment: OP has probably missed listing them.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Because that means $a, b, f, g$ are under-represented and needs to be taken special care of. Had all cyclic sums been there, you could for instance add them all up to figure out the average of all the three-term sums, which would then be a lower bound on $M$.

Comment: @Arthur; but that makes it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M^*$ be the optimal $M$. I will prove the following fact first.

> **FACT:** $M^* \geq \frac{1}{3}$

Proof. There are two cases for the values of $X_1 = a + b + c$ and $X_2 = e + f + g$:

1. at least one of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is $\geq \frac{1}{3}$
2. both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $< \frac{1}{3}$

For the first case, $M \geq \frac{1}{3}$ because $M \geq \max\{X_1,X_2\}$ by definition. For the second case, we will have $d = 1 - X_1 - X_2 > \frac{1}{3}$, making $M \geq c + d + e > \frac{1}{3}$. In summary, $M^* \geq \frac{1}{3}$ since for $\forall a, b, c, d, e, f, g$, we all have $M \geq \frac{1}{3}$.

---

Next question: **can we reach the lower bound $\frac{1}{3}$?** YES! Just let $a = d = g = \frac{1}{3}$ and $b = c = e = f = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a poor answer, but I think the minimum would be when a = d = g = 1/3, the rest being 0, giving M = 1/3.

My trial of thought is that if you were to reduce any of these three values, you'd increase one of the other variables, and the other variables would increase the value of multiple other arguments, resulting in a higher M. Not sure if it's correct, but after some trial and error it's the lowest I could get.